# Can someone explain like I am 5 year-old about this problem from Hastie's ESL Book?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics

I am working through Hastie's ESL book, and I am having a tough time with Question 2.3.  The question is as follows:

[image]

We are considering a nearest neighbor estimate at the origin, and the median distance from the origin to the closest data point is given by this equation.  I have no idea where to begin in terms of trying to derive this.

I know that most data points are closer to the boundary of the sample space, than to any other data point (curse of dimensionality), but I am having trouble translating this into the Linear Algebra / Probability sense.

Comment: What does the "ELI5" in the title mean?  If you want to derive that equation you will need to start with a probability model for points in the ball: what is that model?  (Please don't require your readers to refer to a book or some other site in order to understand your question.)

Comment: @whuber It's an internet acronym that Reddit users use to mean "explain like I'm five [years old]." But usually the acronym is used to mean to explain it with minimal technical jargon, rather than literally explaining a concept to a five-year-old.

Comment: @General Thanks; I figured it was something like that.  But since we ask people to spell out technical acronyms in posts (in part because they are often ambiguous), we ought to be consistent and ask other acronyms to be expanded, too.  How is one to know that something like "ELI5" isn't *also* a specialized acronym or even an abbreviation peculiar to a particular author?

Comment: @whuber I agree -- Acronyms are a terrible hashing scheme.

Comment: You're five years old. All credit to you for wanting to understand ESL, but you'll have to wait until you're six. It's a book for big boys and girls.

Comment: A five year old might start by looking at the one-dimensional case (p = 1). And once that is in hand, take it from there.

Comment: If we are going to have ELI5 spelled out what about ESL?

Comment: You can kind of see that @MarkL.Stone may be onto something since your expression is (p'th power) of something that doesn't depend on $p$.

Comment: @mdewey That's a good point.  There's a big fuzzy line somewhere, because some acronyms become so commonplace they no longer really need spelling out: *eg*, ANOVA, SD, DF, EDA.  Searches of [our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=esl), and of the Web generally, suggest "ESL" might be well on its way into that group. In the present case my hope is that the OP will provide the background necessary to understand the question (it's not even clear what "$n$" stands for--dimension or sample size?), at which point it shouldn't matter much what "ESL" stands for.

Comment: AAA (acronym Angst anecdote): IV means independent variable, except that it probably means instrumental variable if you're an econometrician, implied volatility if you work with financial data, and intravenous if you are a medic.

Comment: @whuber: The question is indeed unclear, I tried to make the question more clear, maybe like this it can be 're-opened' ?

Comment: @Tim; Consider N data points uniformly distributed in a p-dimensional unit ball centered at the origin. Show that the median distance from the origin to the closest data point is given by that expression. Is that so unclear ?

Comment: @fcop  Thank you for including that information. Now that the question is a little clearer, it leaves me wondering what the authors really intend. Normally a "uniform distribution" is understood with respect to the volume measure induced by the *Euclidean* ($L^2$) metric.  Now that an $L^p$ metric is involved, exactly how should we understand "uniform"?  Do the authors state what they mean by that?  Similarly, should we understand "unit ball" to be the $L^p$ unit ball or the $L^2$ unit ball?

Comment: @whuber: well I think you should-re-read my edit, it is about a unit ball in a p-dimensional space, no $L_p$ involved here, and N is the number of datapoints uniformly distributed in that ball.  Is that so unclear ?

Comment: @Tim, sorry, you are right, $n$ and $N$ are the same, I will edit.

Comment: @fcop Please don't be offensive; I have read this passage many times. Presuming "$d(p,*)$" refers to $L^p$ distances, one is *compelled* to wonder exactly what metric is used to define "unit ball" and "uniform."  If that's not what $d(p,*)$ means, then it needs a definition.

Comment: @whuber: sorry, I don't know why you say I  am offensive, in my edit section there is no $L_p$ at all, if you read $d(x,y)$ in one or other question, do you then presume $L_x$ distance ?, but you are right, I was not explicit about distance, but without further details one can assume that distance is 'Euclidean' no ? Especially if I ask about ''layman terms'', but it's ok, I was just trying to help, apparently that is not appreciated so I will undo the edit if you want that ?.

Comment: @whuber: maybe you should read the other comments and then conclude who is most offensive or even 'humiliating' towards a newcomer like Nick ( 116 votes and just asking something he does not understand). When I read all these stupid comments (this is offensive) I decided to try to help.

Comment: @whuber: the goal of this site is, at least in my understanding, to help people understand things, but apparently you should laugh at them ( read the comments), if that is how it works and then you say that someone who tries to help is offensive, then I will look for another hobby and you can delete my account instantantanuously !

Comment: @fcop Please don't do that, I have enjoyed your contributions.

Comment: @fcop I am sorry you feel bad. There's nothing in your recent tirades that seems to allow for a constructive response, so I won't try since I don't want to offend you further. I apologize for any misunderstanding, but please just take some time to cool down before you post anything more. The various edits *made by people other than the original poster* have changed some crucial aspects of the original question. I therefore rolled this post back to the beginning so we can start over and respond to what was actually asked rather than what each individual thinks was asked.

Comment: I gave an answer, but definitely not the one I would give my 5 year old!

Comment: I added a simple summary to the end (maybe OK for a gifted 10 year old?)

Comment: @whuber for the kids on Reddit you could now say "[TIL](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/) what ELI5 means"!

Comment: @fcop Like others, I do hope you stay with us. I'd like to underline that the OP injected a humorous touch at the outset (only an extraordinary 5 year old would understand the question; perhaps Terence Tao might have done). Some of us responded lightheartedly. We are, I trust, **laughing with the OP and absolutely not attempting to mock the OP or their question**, which would, as you imply, be utterly inappropriate. The main culprits are serious supporters of this forum and respectful of it.

Comment: @whuber Flagging the previous comment FYI.

Comment: @whuber: I don't feel bad at all, in fact I am at this site just for fun. I don't know what you mean by tirades but I can guess what you mean. There also your reaction is biased as you seem to insinuate that I am causing trouble.

Comment: @fcop: It'd indeed be a shame if you were to leave. I'm sure any mis-understandings can be ironed out.

Comment: Please see the Solution 2.3 of ESL here https://yuhangzhou88.github.io/ESL_Solution/ESL-Solution/2-Overview-of-Supervised-Learning/ex2-3/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $r$ be distance from the origin, and let $V_0[p]$ be the volume of the unit hypersphere in $p$ dimensions. Then the volume contained in a hypersphere of radius $r$ is

$$V[r]=V_0[p]r^p$$

If we let $P=V[r]/V_0[p]$ denote the fraction of the volume contained within this hypersphere, and define $R=r^p$, then

$$P[R]=R$$

If the data points are uniformly distributed within the unit ball, then for $0\leq R\leq 1$ the above formula is a cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $R$. This is equivalent to a uniform probability density for $R$ over the unit interval, i.e. $p[R]= P'[R] =1$. So, as hinted by Mark Stone in the comments, we can reduce the $p$ dimensional case to an equivalent 1D problem.

Now if we have a single point $R$, then by definition of a CDF we have $\Pr[R\leq \rho]=P[\rho]$ and $\Pr[R\geq \rho]=1-P[\rho]$. If $R_{\min}$ is the smallest value out of $n$ points, and the points are all independent, then the CDF for is given by
$$\Pr[R_{\min}\geq \rho]=\Pr[R\geq \rho]^n=(1-\rho)^n$$
(this is a standard result of univariate [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory)).

By definition of the median, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}=\Pr[(R_{\min})_{\mathrm{med}}\geq R]=(1-R)^n$$
which we can rewrite as
$$(1-d^p)^n=\frac{1}{2}$$
which is equivalent to the desired result.

EDIT: Attempt at "[ELI5](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/)"-style answer, in three parts.

1. For the 1D case with a single point, the distance is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, so the median will be $\frac{1}{2}$.
2. In 1D, the distribution for the minimum over $n$ points is the first case to the $n$-th power.
3. In $p$ dimensions, the distance $r$ is not uniformly distributed, but $r^p$ is.

Comment: Ha ha, I gave the comment that a 5 year old might start by looking at the p = 1 case.  I thought about adding a comment that a 4 year old might not only start with the p = 1 case, but also n = 1. But I figured I'd let the 5 year old figure that out.

Comment: Note that when I answered the question, it was after it had been clarified by @fcop to read: "Consider N data points uniformly distributed in a p-dimensional unit ball centered at the origin. Show that the median distance from the origin to the closest data point is given by ...". So a unit-ball with respect to the $L_2$ norm in $p$ dimensional space. After this the question was rolled back to the original, which differs and is not so clear. (See comment chain under original question.)